# Icon badge number using firebase

Tags: firebase, meteor, phonegap

We have developed an app that is based on Meteor/phonegap and we use Firebase for push notifications.

This is a wall messaging app that delivers a notification to all our users when an update on the wall of contents is delivered.

The problem is that for each phone/user we send 1 push in order to update the icon badge with the corresponding new number and this is taking a while to deliver and also the i/o of our mongo db is heavy because of this.

Im talking about 1000/2000 users nothing big, we are surprised how bad is the system hoging for such a small number of users.

Do you know any alternative to update each user's icon with their custom badge number (depending on how many new messages they have) ?

THanks for your help.

Comment: Really hard to diagnose without code or even a pattern. Are you pushing from firebase to the clients directly using the firebase API or are you using Meteor pub-sub? Does each client get the same number or is the number individualized? Are you pushing new content to all clients too or just numbers? Can the client do the computation of the number itself or does only the server know it?

Comment: @MichelFloyd we are pushing to clients using the firebase API. Each client should have their own badge count, sometimes they get a message + count, otherwise just the badge count. It is possible for the client to compute the number, but then again it depends on the server letting them know there is a change.

Comment: How is MongoDB involved if firebase has the data? Are you using firebase just for push (which would be pointless in Meteor since Meteor uses WebSocket for push) or also as a cache (in which case why is it hitting MongoDB so hard)?

Comment: @MichelFloyd I think the original question is confusing, we are using push notifications for mobile clients (meteor cordova builds). Meteor websockets may not be available if the app is closed.

Comment: @MichelFloyd we use  firebase to send push notifications and icon badget numbers in the phones of our users. Each user has its own notification number on their app icon and it's based on the numbers of unseen messages in their wall of posts.

Comment: ok, sounds like this is a firebase question only then. You should still show code.